# Extending classes and using class attributes in parent class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have tried to solve React's annoying `bind` requirement as follows:

```
class ExtendedComponent extends React.Component {

    custom_functions: [];

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let self = this;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.custom_functions.length; i++) {
            let funcname = this.custom_functions[i];
            self[funcname] = self[funcname].bind(self);
        }
    }
}

class OrderMetricsController extends ExtendedComponent {

    custom_functions: ['refreshTableOnDateChange', 'load', 'refreshTableOnTabChange'];

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        ...
```

This will preclude the need for

```
this.refreshTableOnDateChange = this.refreshTableOnDateChange.bind(this);
```

For now, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` where the problem is `this.custom_functions.length`.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "attributes." What do you mean when you say "class attributes"?

Comment: `custom_functions: […];` for sure looks like a syntax error inside a `class`. What flavour of javascript are you using?

Comment: If the use of `bind` within ES6 class syntax annoys you, have you considered _not_ using ES6 class syntax and revert to using React helper functions like `.createClass` and `createElement`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
custom_functions: ['refreshTableOnDateChange', 'load', 'refreshTableOnTabChange'];
```

is type annotation, and `this.custom_functions` is still undefined. Instead, it should be a property initializer:

```
custom_functions = ['refreshTableOnDateChange', 'load', 'refreshTableOnTabChange'];
```

Or considering its static nature, `custom_functions` can be a static property:

```
static custom_functions = ['refreshTableOnDateChange', 'load', 'refreshTableOnTabChange'];
```

In this case it is accessible in constructor as `this.constructor.custom_functions`.

There's nothing annoying in `bind`, this is how JS works.

For strict naming conventions, the methods can be bound automatically by traversing through method names, for example the ones which names match `on*` or `*Handler`:

```
const uniquePropNames = new Set([
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this),  
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype)
]);

for (const propName of uniquePropNames) {
  if (typeof this[propName] === 'function' && /^on[A-Z]|.Handler$/.test(propName)) {
     this[propName] = this[propName].bind(this);
  }
}
```

A good alternative is [`@autobind` decorator from `core-decorators`](https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators.js#autobind).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should a prototype property or at least `static`, not initialised in every instance?

Comment: @Bergi This was drop-in fix. But thanks, I agree that static property suits the case better.